# OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296 - no such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

End of my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["ls /etc"]
```

Terminal:

```
...Rest of the building  above is fine
Step 8/8 : ENTRYPOINT ["ls /etc"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ea1f33b8ab22
Successfully built ea1f33b8ab22
Successfully tagged redis:latest
k@Karls ~/dev/docker_redis (master) $ docker run -d -p 6379:6379 --name red redis
71d75058b94f088ef872b08a115bc12cece288b53fe26d67960fe139953ed5c4
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"ls /etc\": stat ls /etc: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

For some reason, it won't find the directory `/etc`. I did a `pwd` and the current working directory is `/`. I also did a `ls /` on the entrypoint and that displayed the `/etc` directory fine.

Comment: Try `["ls", "/etc"] `. If that doesn't work, do you change user in your docker file?

Answer (score 9):

> OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296

In my experience this is an error with the docker daemon itself, not the container you are trying to run. Try deleting all containers, restarting the daemon. I think we also had to clean up the docker networks.

Comment: `if [[ $(docker ps -q) ]] ; then docker kill $(docker ps -q) ; else true ; fi && if [[ $(docker ps -aq) ]] ; then docker rm $(docker ps -aq) ; else true ; fi ; sudo service docker restart`

Answer (score 3):

I appear to be having the same issue. Here is what I am doing.

Dockerfile

```
FROM gcc:7.2.0
COPY  src/ /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN set -x gcc -o myapp main.c
CMD ["./myapp"]
```

Build

```
$ docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/6 : FROM gcc:7.2.0
...
 ---> 3ec35c7d2396
Successfully built 3ec35c7d2396
Successfully tagged test:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a 
non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context 
will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and 
reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

Run

```
$ docker run -it test
D:\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create 
failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: 
\"./myapp\": stat ./myapp: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

Changed CMD to ENTRYPOINT and removed the set -x seemed to resolve the problem. Though we are still unsure what the cause was or if this will also work for you.
Make sure that /etc exists or is created as the main.c wasn't compiling.

Dockerfile

```
FROM gcc:7.2.0
COPY  src/ /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN gcc -o myapp main.c
ENTRYPOINT ["./myapp"]
```

Answer (score 1):

On OSX, I fixed it by clearing the volume data manually. Close docker, and remove everything in `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker`

Answer (score 1):

I've expirienced the same issue after updating my Windows credentials, try following:  Docker settings > Shared Drives > Reset credentials > Select drives again > Apply and re-enter your credentials. This solved the problem for me multiple times

Answer (score 1):

The command you are trying to execute inside the container does not exist. In this case `ls /etc` does not exist in the image. There's a `/bin/ls` binary, but not a `/bin/"ls /etc"` binary, which itself would be invalid since the name of a file on the filesystem cannot include a `/`, though it can include a space.

Of course what you wanted to run was `ls` with the argument `/etc`, and for that, you need to separate each argument if you run with the exec syntax.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["ls", "/etc"]
```

Or if you wanted to allow a shell to parse the string, same way as if you were at a bash prompt inside the container running `ls /etc` on the command line, then switch to the string syntax that runs a shell:

```
ENTRYPOINT ls /etc
```